# Package installed by Nix not in Mate desktop menu

Tags: menu, nix

I have used Nix package manager to install Abiword in a Slackware/Salix install with Mate desktop. The application runs fine but it has not appeared in the main Menu. Is this usual for applications installed by Nix?

Comment: Do you have a `.desktop` file somewhere in `~/.nix-profile/` ? For example in `~/.nix-profile/etc/xdg`? (Just a guess, better use `find ~/.nix-profile -name '*.desktop'`)

Comment: No, there is no such file on my system.

Comment: It will be very useful if Nix package manager could have a GUI front-end. This front-end may have synaptic-like (used with Debian etc) package management and also a menu from which all applications installed in Nix package system can be run.

Comment: What are the values of the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and  `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` environment variables? As for the GUI: Nix and NixOS are still relatively young projects. With a further growing user base there probably will be a graphical frontend in the near future.

Comment: The command 'export | grep XDG' gives XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/gdm/" and  XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=".....long number....."

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on openSUSE plasma-desktop by adding the following to my bashrc

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=~/.local/share/:~/.nix-profile/share:/usr/share
cp -f ~/.nix-profile/share/applications/*.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Then logging out or running `kbuildsycoca4` rebuilds the start menu.

When I only set the `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, the icons would appear in the start menu. However kdelibs is trying to make those .desktop files executable and add a xdg-open shebang to them, which does not work since .nix-profile is not writeable.
Thus it was also necessary to copy the desktop files to a `~/.local/share/applications/`, which however also needs the XDG_DATA_DIRS set to `~/.nix-profile`, because the application icons still reside there.